# jQuery UI sortable - replace content of dropped item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have three blocks,  "draggable", "sortable" and "droppable"

Inside "draggable" I have few elements built like this:

```
<li class="draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" id="header-1">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
</li>
```

These elements can be dragged into "sortable" and the elements dragged here can be dropped into "droppable" which is removing them from "sortable" it's basically deleting them.

How can I replace the image dropped into "sortable" with a new one without replacing the image from "draggable"?

Here's what I've tried:

I've tried adding  this  to the "draggable":

```
start: function (event, ui) {
     $(this).addClass('testing');
 }
```

This is adding  ".testing" class to the current dragged item.

and I've added this to the "sortable" :

```
     receive: function (event, ui) {
     $('.testing').replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">');
```

The problem here is that is replacing the whole markup including the "li" parent and I want to replace just the "img" element.

Here is a **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dajec/5/edit?html,js,output)**  of how this works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for misunderstanding the question. What you've described is: modifying the dropped element without modifying the original `draggable` (let me know if I misunderstood again).

This is usually done using the `helper` option, typically with a function, but the `helper: "clone"` you have can also work. This will result in a clone of the `draggable` being dropped. That means you can just restrict your selectors to the current container, and you don't need the `".testing"` class at all (though of course feel free to keep it if it makes it easier for you to see what's going on):

```
receive: function (event, ui) {
    $('.testing', this).replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">');
    // or...
    $(this).find('.testing').replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">');
    // or without the superfluous class...
    $(this).find('li.draggable').replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">');
    // or to keep the li tags as per my original post's suggestion...
    $('li.draggable > img', this).replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">');
}
```

Remember, jQuery's `clone` only makes a copy of the DOM node, none of its jQuery properties are preserved. The dropped helper will no longer be a `draggable` widget (though in your case you're using a `sortable` which will still let you drag it)

Comment: I've tried this, but it still modify the image item from the "draggable" block and I don't want this, it should modify just the image dropped into the "sortable" block

Comment: This seems to work, but I need to be able to remove the dropped element inside the "sortable" block when I drag it to "#sidebar-wrapper". This is the code responsible for it, you can check it also in the jsbin:  `$("#sidebar-wrapper").droppable({
     accept: 'li',
     drop: function (event, ui) {
         ui.helper.remove();
     }
 });` Is this possible?

Comment: I've been trying for hours again today and I can't seem to make it like this? Do you have any idea?

Comment: [Is this what you mean?](http://jsfiddle.net/tt9veu9n/) For that, you just need to `.remove()` the `ui.draggable`; and either preserve the `<li>`, or `accept: "img"`

Answer (score 0):

On receive event, get previous dropped element. If this element exists append to sender.

```
$(".connect").on("sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
  var prevChild = $(event.target).children().not(ui.item);
  if(prevChild.length > 0){
    $(ui.sender).append(prevChild);
  }
});
```